# Dropdown menu appearing upwards instead of downwards

Tags: html, css

The code can be run here: https://jsfiddle.net/v0ey36cn/ and relevant HTML (containing CSS) code is below:

```js
function toggleState() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #0072C6;
}

/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */

.topnav {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  visibility: none;
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 100%;
}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */

.topnav a {
  float: right;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* Hide the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

/* Dropdown menu */

.dropDownP {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropDown {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}

.dropDownContent {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10000;
}

.dropDownContent a {
  float: none;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropDown:hover .dropDownContent {
  display: block;
}

.dropDownP:hover,
.dropDown:hover .dropDownP,
.dropDown a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(221, 221, 221, 0.85);
  /* grey */
  color: black;
}

/* Small screen settings */

@media screen and (max-width: 106px) {
  .topnav a:not(: first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
  .dropDown {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 106px) {
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: fixed;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
  }
  .topnav.responsive img {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<body style="text-align:center;">

    <div class="header">
      <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="toggleState()">&#9776;</a>
        <a href="?l3">Link 3</a>
        <a href="?l2">Link 2</a>
        <div class="dropDown">
          <div class="dropDownContent">
            <a href="?o1">Option 1</a>
            <a href="?o2">Option 2</a>
          </div>
          <a class="dropDownP">Dropdown</a>
        </div>
        <a href="?l1">Link 1</a>
      </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

I use skrollr (the skrollr.min.js file can be found on [github](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr/blob/master/dist/skrollr.min.js)) and the rest of the details can be seen directly from my site above. I have two questions:

1) How can I correct the dropdown menus to appear downwards on hover, as they should, instead of this upwards weird thing? What am I doing wrong in the CSS?

2) How can I make the dropdown menus not extend the whole navigation bar when the dropdown appears?

3) How can I make a special dropdown for small screens, such that the dropdown appears directly under the stacked "main menu"? (see the code on my site, there is also code for mobile main menu, but not for the special dropdown I would like to request here)

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: @j08691 ok, I will update to reflect! Please help if you can! Thanks!

Comment: Is your link supposed to work? The DNS does not resolve for me?

Comment: @MrWhite Yes, it is supposed to work...

Comment: The link is not working... Why don't you recreate it here using the code snippet tool? That way you'd get more help for sure!

Comment: @Salketer I am sorry, I uploaded code to jsFiddle and here it is (the post was also updated): https://jsfiddle.net/v0ey36cn/

Comment: Please, do not change the question's code! Imagine someone comes to it next year with the same problem, they won't understand a thing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because your HTML is wrong. You should put the content of your submenu after the menu text.

Replace

```
<div class="dropDown">
    <div class="dropDownContent">
        <a href="?o1">Option 1</a>
        <a href="?o2">Option 2</a>
    </div>
    <a class="dropDownP">Dropdown</a>
</div>
```

By

```
<div class="dropDown">
    <a class="dropDownP">Dropdown</a>
    <div class="dropDownContent">
        <a href="?o1">Option 1</a>
        <a href="?o2">Option 2</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, to make the dropdown not take any place in the menu (so it doesn't make it expand) you need to position it absolutely.

```
.dropDownContent{
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
}
```

As for your third question, you need to use media queries. I can't really guide you more on this part as there are too many useless elements in your fiddle.

Comment: I made the above corrections, but it still displays incorrectly: https://jsfiddle.net/v0ey36cn/3/ (I also removed all redundant code so now you may be able to help me not with media queries (I know how to do that once the style changes have been decided upon) but how I can make a stacked sub-menu appear)

Comment: Remove the overflow: hidden; from your menu. And see answer, I corrected the CSS slightly.

Comment: And about my third question, how can I make a sub-menu appear inline when all main-menu items have float:none, which means that blocks appear one below other (you can see my very simple media queries on the above fiddle)?

Comment: use `display:inline` or `display:inline-block`, you should search the web a little, this is very very basic knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the order of elements is wrong here:

```
<div class="dropDown">
      <div class="dropDownContent">
        <a href="?o1">Option 1</a>
        <a href="?o2">Option 2</a>
      </div>
      <a class="dropDownP">Dropdown</a>
    </div>
```

`<a class="dropDownP">Dropdown</a>`  should be *above*  `<div class="dropDownContent">` in order to be above of it when the dropdown becomes visible.

But apart from that, your HTML structure should be different. You are using block elements, which spread the dropdown across the whole wodth. Use a `ul` instead.

```
<div class="header">
  <ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="toggleState()">&#9776;</a></li>
    <li><a href="?l3">Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="?l2">Link 2</a></li> 
    <li class="dropDown">Dropdown
      <ul class="dropDownContent">
        <li><a href="?o1">Option 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="?o2">Option 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="?l1">Link 1</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And you'll need the according CSS, but that can be found in pretty much every online tutoria about dropdown menus (main menu items with `position: relative`, submenu `position: absolute`)